# Czech characters display issue on WebClient download string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello I have this code that downloads text to string like this:

```
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {

            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-2");

            string vysledek = client.DownloadString("http://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.txt?date=13.09.2013");
            string nova = vysledek;
        }
```

But the problem is with the ISO. I found that Czech language has this so I inserted it into the Header but nothing has changed.

Would somebody help me solve this out?

This is example I get:

> zemÄ›|mÄ›na|mnoĹľstvĂ­|kĂłd|kurz
>
> AustrĂˇlie|dolar|1|AUD|17,929

Also I would like to ask how can I read line of string that contains e.g. "AUD"

Comment: What makes you think server respects "Accept-Charset" header? Play with making requests with Fiddler and see if anything changes when you pass different values for the header. I bet server simply ignores incoming headers and returns file as-is in whatever encoding it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string vysledek = client.DownloadString("http://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni_trhy/devizovy_trh/kurzy_devizoveho_trhu/denni_kurz.txt?date=13.09.2013");

    var table = vysledek.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' })
                .Select(line => line.Split('|').ToList())
                .Skip(2)
                .ToList();

}
```

Comment: Thank you again for an awesome answer. May I please ask how can I display one of those decimal values in a desired line? I'm sorry for asking but I'm not sure about that. I see that table contains 35 lines and each line has 5 items. But I'm not sure how can I display them